# How to add an xml file as a resource to Windows Forms exe

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

I have a Windows forms C# application.
I want to add an xml file to this .exe
This xml file must be part of the .exe file.
How can I do that and how can I access the xml file in the program.

What I have tried is this:

```
Stream st = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("CApp.xmlfile.xml");
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(st);

doc = XElement.Load(reader);
```

Build Action for xml file is "Embedded Resource"

Comment: See http://www.cs.nyu.edu/~vs667/articles/embed_executable_tutorial/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the properties of the project you want to add it to, go to the Resources -> Add Resource (down arrow) add existing file.

Then name it however you want.

Then you'll see it in the solution in your project -> Properties (folder) Resources.Designer.cs file.  To load it, say you named the resource(the file) CAppxmlfile.

You load it with `XElement resource = XElement.Parse(Properties.Resources.CAppxmlfile);`