# C# Xml files when creating exe application

Tags: c#

I'm planning to build my winform into a .exe file. I'm just wondering what to do with the XML files that my application needs?

I did some research and found out that I can add the XML files in the Resource folder before creating a .exe file.
Or I need to create a setup file? When the user runs the setup file, the XML files will be installed into their pc.
Now I wonder which one is the best way to go for,

**Note:** XML files might get modified by the user.

Comment: Please view existed discussion thread

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7720862/how-to-add-an-xml-file-as-a-resource-to-windows-forms-exe

Comment: Minh Nguyen, there's a user below saying if we want to modify the xml files during application running, we can't put it into the Resources folder. Is there another way?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to ship the XML files as seperate to the .EXE then you can set the Copy to Output Directory to Copy if newer. (click on file and then go to properties).

OR if you want it as part of the .EXE I think you can change the Build Action to Embedded Resource.

I personally would create a Setup as per your edit and include the XML files. I usually just add everthing from the bin/release folder that is needed when I create a setup file.

Comment: Depends, how are you creating the setup file. inno setup? NSIS? One Click Installer?

Answer (score 0):

You could either deploy the necessary files along with the executable in the same folder or embed them as resources (if they are read-only). If you need to modify them do not embed them as resources into the executable.

Comment: Yes, Darin Dimitrov, the xml files will be modified... So, is it that now I have to create a setup file and when the user run the setup file, the xml files will be installed into the user's pc? Is this the way?

Comment: Yes, this is one possibility to include them with your deployment package.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way depends on how you intend to use the files. If the files always are deployed together with your application, the application never writes to them and they are never upgraded without upgrading the application, you can go with them embedded as resources.

If you need to update them separately from the application, you need to have them as physical files.

You don't necessarely need a installation package, unless you need to apply some logic during setup, such as updating the content of the setup based on user input or to check preconditions. The application can just be copied into place regardless of if you have embedded the files or not.

Comment: PHeiberg, may I know how do you add the xml files when you create the setup file?

Comment: @Coolguy - that's a perfect fit for another question. Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtzawcsz(v=vs.100).aspx) for an overview of deployment options.