# C# Fill Listview with data from XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq, listview, dataset

Im working on a simple project. I have windows form and when the Form open I want my "Userslistview" with 3 Columns to be filled with data from my XML which is also created by the program.

I have tried a couple of methodes but the listview just stays empty.
So here's the Load event code im using

```
    private void MainMenu_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string xmlfile = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Users.xml";
        if (!File.Exists(xmlfile))
        {
            return;
        }
        UserslistView.View = View.Details;
        UserslistView.GridLines = true;
        UserslistView.Sorting = SortOrder.Descending;
        UserslistView.FullRowSelect = true;
        UserslistView.Columns.Add("Active", 80);
        UserslistView.Columns.Add("username", 120);
        UserslistView.Columns.Add("Last Logon", 120);

        UserslistView.Items.Clear();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.ReadXml(xmlfile);
        ListViewItem item;
        foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables["user"].Rows)
        {
            item = new ListViewItem(new string[]
             {
                dr["username"].ToString(),
                dr["USERID"].ToString(),
                dr["lastlogon"].ToString()

            });
            UserslistView.Items.Add(item);

        }
    }

and here's the XMl im using
```

[image]

## UPDATE 1

I swapped my code for this.

```
private void MainMenu_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UserslistView.View = View.Details;
        UserslistView.GridLines = true;
        UserslistView.FullRowSelect = true;
        UserslistView.Columns.Add("Active", 100);
        UserslistView.Columns.Add("username", 120);
        //UserslistView.Columns.Add("Last Logon", 100);

        string xmlfile = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Users.xml";
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        try
        {
            doc.Load(xmlfile);
            foreach (XmlNode n in doc.SelectNodes("/Users//user"))
            {
                ListViewItem li = new ListViewItem(n.SelectSingleNode("username").InnerText);
                li.SubItems.Add(n.SelectSingleNode("lastlogon").InnerText);
                UserslistView.Items.Add(li);
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

The count for the node is 2.
But listview still stays empty

Comment: curious, have you debugged this?

Answer (score 0):

First make sure your xml is available in your project. I followed this example: [How to add an xml file as a resource to Windows Forms exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7720862/how-to-add-an-xml-file-as-a-resource-to-windows-forms-exe)

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml.Linq;

private void MainMenu_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        UserslistView.View = View.Details;
            UserslistView.GridLines = true;
            UserslistView.Sorting = SortOrder.Descending;
            UserslistView.Columns.Add("Active", 80);
            UserslistView.Columns.Add("username", 120);
            UserslistView.Columns.Add("Last Logon", 120);

            UserslistView.Items.Clear();


            var doc = XDocument.Parse(Properties.Resources.Users);
            var output = from x in doc.Root.Elements("user")
                         select new ListViewItem(new []
                         {
                             x.Element("USERID").Value,
                             x.Element("username").Value,
                             x.Element("lastlogon").Value

                         });
            UserslistView.Items.AddRange(output.ToArray());

        }
    }
```

Comment: I dont Think I need to add the xml to the resources , or do I?

Comment: I have a combobox on a second form which is filled correctly with just the usernames.

When I try to Parse it states that the root element in invalid.
When I debug it does seem to contain the item collection, but will not populate the listview, what am I missing here.
Quick side note I am kinda new to c# so any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `XDocument` and parse your `Xml`

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(file path);

    var nodes = doc.Descendants("user").Select(e=> new ListViewItem( new [] { 

        e.Element("username").Value,
e.Element("USERID").Value,

        //e.Element("password").Value,
        e.Element("lastlogon").Value
    })).ToArray();



UserslistView.Items.AddRange(nodes);
```

Comment: I tried using the parse method but it says my root element is invalid

Comment: @JeffReek it should be _Load_, parse is used when we have xml string. Corrected, try now.

Comment: just changed it, 
Listview still stays empty.
Really dont know what it wrong

Comment: Also comment out password from the list. Updated.